# Unable to make the .each() function execute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a responsive carousel and for that, I need to execute a function to set the siblings of the item.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-11 col-md-12 col-centered">

        <div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="2500">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="carousel-col col-xs-12">
                        <div class="block red img-responsive"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/01_103.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"><p class="title-slide">MESSI</p></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="carousel-col col-xs-12">
                        <div class="block green img-responsive"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/01_103.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"><p class="title-slide">MESSI</p></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="carousel-col col-xs-12">
                        <div class="block blue img-responsive"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/01_103.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"><p class="title-slide">MESSI</p></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="carousel-col col-xs-12">
                        <div class="block yellow img-responsive"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/01_103.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"><p class="title-slide">MESSI</p></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <div class="left carousel-control">
                <a href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="right carousel-control">
                <a href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript tag that goes with this is this.

```
<script language="javascript">


    $('.carousel[data-type="multi"].item').each(function() {
      var next = $(this).next();
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }
     next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

      for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        next = next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
          next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

       next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
     }
   });


</script>
```

But the probelm is that the each function is never executed. I used Google Chrome debugger and placed a breakpoint on the function definiton. That's how I know that function is being executed. I'm just getting started with this stuff so I might be missing some thing obvious here.

Comment: And I also tried to enclose the function within `$(document).ready(function() {}`, but got same results.

Comment: Only add a space before `.item`: `$('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item')`

Comment: FYI, the `language` attribute has been deprecated for like a decade. Just use an unadorned script tag. Also put your JavaScript into a separate file so you get proper tool support and better organization. `<script src="index.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the element with class `item` is inside the carousel element you have to add space before `.item`. Change you selector To

```
$('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item')
```

```js
$('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function() {

  console.log(this);
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
 next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    next = next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

   next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-11 col-md-12 col-centered">

  <div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="2500">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
              <div class="carousel-col col-xs-12">
                  <div class="block red img-responsive"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/01_103.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"><p class="title-slide">MESSI</p></a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <div class="carousel-col col-xs-12">
                  <div class="block green img-responsive"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/01_103.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"><p class="title-slide">MESSI</p></a></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <div class="carousel-col col-xs-12">
                  <div class="block blue img-responsive"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/01_103.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"><p class="title-slide">MESSI</p></a></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <div class="carousel-col col-xs-12">
                  <div class="block yellow img-responsive"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/01_103.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"><p class="title-slide">MESSI</p></a></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <div class="left carousel-control">
          <a href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="right carousel-control">
          <a href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user8114666, what is not working? Your question was about the `.each()` not executing.....I don't know the code inside the the function and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually the problem is that the pointer is not even entering the function. I tried what you suggested but still same results.

Comment: I placed a breakpoint on the function definition and tried step by step and it just skips the function.

Comment: @user8114666, I have added a `console.log` inside the function. See how that is printing all the matching elements.... that means the function is executing...

Comment: Okay. I'll try this in the morning. I'm really tired and can't work anymore.

Comment: @user8114666, you are most welcome.....grate to know that it is working :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:- Place your code inside `$(document).ready(){});` function and also  add space before .item `$('.carousel[data-type="multi"] > .item')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function() {
      var next = $(this).next();
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }
     next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

      for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        next = next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
          next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

       next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
     }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-11 col-md-12 col-centered">

        <div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="2500">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="carousel-col col-xs-12">
                        <div class="block red img-responsive"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/01_103.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"><p class="title-slide">MESSI</p></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="carousel-col col-xs-12">
                        <div class="block green img-responsive"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/01_103.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"><p class="title-slide">MESSI</p></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="carousel-col col-xs-12">
                        <div class="block blue img-responsive"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/01_103.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"><p class="title-slide">MESSI</p></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="carousel-col col-xs-12">
                        <div class="block yellow img-responsive"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/01_103.jpg" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"><p class="title-slide">MESSI</p></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Controls -->
            <div class="left carousel-control">
                <a href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="right carousel-control">
                <a href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```